# Ivy Generator Add-on Horizontal grow

Tags: add-on

How to make ivy grow horizontally with Ivy Gen add-on?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Increase the "branching probability". I'm trying to do the same here and it looks to be the answer. Still testing.